# Substituir NAs por valores de outra coluna

Tags: r, dplyr

Como substituir valores NAs de uma coluna pelos mesmos valores de outra coluna? Exemplo:

```
A <- c(2, 6, 1, 7, 3)

B <- c(6, NA, 7, 2, NA)

dados <- data.frame(A, B)

d <- dados %>% mutate(C = A + B)

d

  A  B  C
1 2  6  8
2 6 NA NA
3 1  7  8
4 7  2  9
5 3 NA NA
```

Eu gostaria que os dados com NAs da nova coluna "C" criada, fossem substituídos pelos mesmos valores das linhas da coluna A.

Answer (score 3):

Com *dplyr*, pode usar a função `coalesce`:

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% mutate(C = coalesce(C, A))
#>   A  B C
#> 1 2  6 8
#> 2 6 NA 6
#> 3 1  7 8
#> 4 7  2 9
#> 5 3 NA 3
```

Com R base, pode usar `is.na` e indexação lógica:

```
i <- is.na(d$C)

d$C[i] <- d$A[i]
```

*data.table* possui a função `fcoalesce` ("fast coalesce"):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(d)

d[, C := fcoalesce(C, A)]
```

Comment: Sem previamente criar `d` pode ser `dados %>% mutate(C = coalesce(A+B, A))`. Criando `d`:  `d<-dados; setDT(d)[, C := fcoalesce(A + B, A)]`.

Comment: Sim, existem várias formas de gerar a soma diretamente sem NAs é só que não era essa a pergunta. Penso que fazer soma removendo NAs mereceria uma pergunta própria, para facilitar futuras buscas no site.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o teste lógico `ifelse` para avaliar o vetor.
No teu exemplo, a coluna C é a soma de A+B ou A+A.

```
library(dplyr)

A <- c(2, 6, 1, 7, 3)

B <- c(6, NA, 7, 2, NA)

dados <- data.frame(A, B)

d <- dados %>% mutate(C = A + ifelse(B %in% NA, yes = A, no = B))

d

  A  B  C
1 2  6  8
2 6 NA 12
3 1  7  8
4 7  2  9
5 3 NA  6
```

Se você quiser que C seja a soma de A+B quando B não for `NA` e C seja apenas o valor de A quando B for `NA`, segue o exemplo.

```
d <- dados %>% mutate(C = ifelse(B %in% NA, yes = A, no = A + B))

d

  A  B C
1 2  6 8
2 6 NA 6
3 1  7 8
4 7  2 9
5 3 NA 3
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, eu consegui! É igual a segunda opção.

Answer (score 2):

Mais uma solução, numa só linha de código.

```
d <- dados %>% mutate(C = if_else(is.na(B), A, A + B))

d
#  A  B C
#1 2  6 8
#2 6 NA 6
#3 1  7 8
#4 7  2 9
#5 3 NA 3
```