# Somar colunas selecionadas, excluindo NAs

Tags: r

Esta pergunta é inspirada [nesta outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/528713/117168). Dado um *data.frame* qualquer, o objetivo é gerar uma variável com a soma de algumas colunas, excluindo os NAs.

```
dados <- data.frame(
  X = letters[4:8],
  Y = 1:5,
  A = c(2, 6, 1, NA, 3),
  B = c(6, NA, 7, 2, NA),
  C = c(1, 5, NA, 2, NA))
```

O resultado desejado:

```
X Y  A  B  C somaABC
d 1  2  6  1       9
e 2  6 NA  5      11
f 3  1  7 NA       8
g 4 NA  2  2       4
h 5  3 NA NA       3
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra alternativa usando o `dplyr` é

```
library(dplyr)

dados %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(somaABC = sum(c_across(A:C),na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Rowwise: 
  X         Y     A     B     C somaABC
  <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 d         1     2     6     1       9
2 e         2     6    NA     5      11
3 f         3     1     7    NA       8
4 g         4    NA     2     2       4
5 h         5     3    NA    NA       3
```

Em que o comando `rowwise` aplicará a função abaixo dela por linha. E o comando `c_across` permite esta interação ao selecionar múltiplas colunas.

Answer (score 0):

Usando `rowSums(..., na.rm = TRUE)` nas colunas selecionadas:

**R base**

```
dados$somaABC <- rowSums(dados[c("A", "B", "C")], na.rm = TRUE)
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dados)

dados[, somaABC := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = A:C]
```

**dplyr**

library(dplyr)

```
dados <- dados %>% mutate(somaABC = rowSums(select(., A:C), na.rm = TRUE))
```